# Remote Powershell: New-SPUser : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005)

Tags: development, powershell, access-denied, continuous-integration

I am running a **remote** powershell script which attempts to setup a web-application and site collection and then attempts to add a user to that site collection.

I receive the following error:

New-SPUser : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005)

This **does not** occur if I run the same script locally with the same administrative account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to run GrantAccessToProcessIdentity on your web-application

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity <Identity>
$webApp.GrantAccessToProcessIdentity(<User>)
```

Comment: This is such a useful solution. I re-discover it second year in a row for the fifth time. I wish I would just remember. Thank you for posting it.